# starting multiple process in multiple threads elixir

Tags: multithreading, elixir

I am simply doing few operations against a list of servers from db as

```
list_servers()
|> Enum.map(fn(server) ->
  go_through_and_email(server)
end)
```

my only question is that, is there any possibility to start each `go_through_email(server)` process for each server, separately? Right now, It gets completed for the first one and then goes to the 2nd one. Can we run them parallelly? as `list_servers` could have 100 or 100+ objects.

I don't want to use `Task.await` or `Task.async`, are there any other options to explore?

Comment: Why don't you want to use those `Task` functions?

Comment: I have a very bad experience from this in past, Each and every time, I put things in Task, they only get timed out. and FAILED..

Comment: You probably just needed to specify a larger timeout to `Task.await`. The default is 5 seconds. A simple Task.async + await will spawn all the tasks at the same time though. You probably want to spawn in batches of e.g. 10 I guess (especially if the list is large)?

Comment: Okay, what you are saying sounds good, But I have no idea and I haven't done anything with it in past as well. the maximum, I experienced is to Remove Task.await, in our actual system, Do you have any example to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GenServer as well. If list_servers() and go_through_and_email() will be defined as helper functions you should be able to do something like this:

```
defmodule ExampleGenServer do
  use GenServer

  ## Client API
  def start_link(name) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: name)
  end

  def go_through(name) do
    GenServer.cast(name, {:go_through, name})
  end

  ## Server API / Callbacks
  def init(initial_state) do
    {:ok, initial_state}
  end

  def handle_cast({:go_through, name}, state) do
    state = go_through_and_email(server)
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_info({:some_info}, state) do
    # stuff
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  ## Helper functions
  defp list_servers() do
    # stuff
  end

  defp go_through_and_email() do
    # stuff
  end
end
```

Then you could create new instance of GenServer in a loop:

```
list_servers()
|> Enum.map(fn(server) ->
  ExampleGenserver.start_link(server)
end)
```

I've made it quickly during a break so I could miss / mess up something ;)
If you will need some additional details about GenServers you may refer to my [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Kociamber/cc10ce05a05ecf4f628e3d06e68bb5d4). It describes GenServer client / server API, messaging and arg passing ;) 
And one more thing, remember about GenServer teardown! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Task.async_stream/3`. It allows you to pass an enumerable and run a function on them, with an option to limit the maximum number of tasks to run in parallel using the `max_concurrency` option. The default `timeout` is 5000ms, you'll probably want to specify a larger one.

Here's a small example:

```
1..20
|> Task.async_stream(fn x ->
  :timer.sleep(1000)
  x
end, max_concurrency: 4, timeout: 10_000)
|> Enum.each(&IO.inspect/1)
```

If you run this, you should see `{:ok, 1}` to `{:ok, 20}` printed in batches of 4 every second. The whole thing should finish in 5 seconds, as expected when running a 1 second sleep in batches of 4 for 20 items.

Comment: Thanks, But will it be so much to ask for a little small implementation of GenServer could play a part in this?

Comment: Not sure I understand that.. What do you want to do with a GenServer here? Is `list_servers` returning a list of GenServers or a list of info about actual servers?

Comment: I was saying. is that possible to start each process through GenServer? `list_servers` is getting a list of structs from db..

Comment: Yes, it is and I would use it. I will try to prepare an example soon.

Comment: Maybe he would like to supervise it? But indeed, it can be easily done without it.

Comment: Yep, `Task.Supervisor` can be used for that. One useful feature of `Task.async_stream` is that it allows limiting concurrency. You probably don't want to initiate 100+ SSH connections at the exact same moment.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to use `Task.start`, but you don't want to use Task module.

Another thing is to get rid of `go_through_email(server)` in the `Enum.map`. Assuming that `server` is DB Server, you should create a GenServers that will communicate with DB servers and in the `map` you would send a message to each of the GenServers.

```
Enum.map(list_of_gen_servers, &send_message_to_go_through_email(&1))
```

And then every GenServer would handle the code in the parallel. Of course you would need to have the list of GenServers prepared. It's definitely better approach than using `send / receive` explicitly.

**Edit**:

Task module would be great if you want to `fire and forget`. GenServers would be better choice, if you would frequently access DB servers and they allow to have full control *how* the communication model should looks like.

Comment: servers are actually , few dedicated servers where I have IP username and Password and I am going to run few commands through SSH

Comment: Yes, so each GenServer - you can generate them in as you wish, would comunnicate with the DB Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can also defer the real task to another supervisor. I can't decide whether a simple function or a gen server is needed in your case, but have a look at `simple_one_for_one` [supervisor](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#module-simple-one-for-one).

This kind of supervisor is a perfect fit for this kind of needs (sending emails, if I got it correctly).

PS. You said no `Task`, but playing with `Task.async_stream` and timeouts is another fit option too.